# In an Angular.js controller's scope function code doesn't run below a $timeout statement inside

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-controller, angularjs-ng-click, angularjs-timeout

I have a button for which I have set `ng-click="refresh()"`. The console logs before the timeout function logs correctly but the console log inside the `$timeout` block and after the block doesn't seem to log. If I remove the `$timeout` block every console log works. I even checked with `$interval` instead of `$timeout` but same behaviour.

I wanted to do something like this [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/tXnA9tKJg22hBuXNSepv?p=preview&preview)

I'm using Angular.js 1.4.0

This is my implementation inside the controller

```js
      $scope.refreshing ={state: false};
      $scope.refresh = function(){
        console.log($scope);
        $scope.refreshing.state = true;
        $scope.search(); //sends an http request and loads results.
        console.log('this logs');
        // $scope.refreshing.state = false;
        $timeout(function(){
           console.log('this doesnt log')
           $scope.refreshing.state = false;
         },2000);
        console.log('this doesnt log')

      }
```

Comment: Sounds like it's crashing. Any errors in the console? Maybe `$timeout` isn't defined.

Comment: Yes. You can find all the built-in AngularJS services listed [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service). Can you edit your question to include the controller function definition, as well as the code where you're registering the controller in your angular.module()? And to be clear, you're saying there are no errors in your JS console?

Comment: You're not answering my question about the JS console errors

Comment: I need to see the definition of your controller function to make sure you're using the dependency injection properly

Comment: or great now it makes sense. i havent added the $timeout in the dependancy array

Comment: That makes sense. As to why you're not getting `Uncaught ReferenceError: $timeout is not defined` in your JS console, I have no clue. Are you catching the exception and not logging it by any chance?

Comment: im also not doing anything as such also vscode didnt even warn or anything. im new to ang1 so i miss these things

Comment: No problem. Your IDE wouldn't be able to warn you of this kind of issue because it has no way of knowing about the dependency injection behind the scenes and whether or not a function parameter like `$timeout` has been defined at runtime. My apologies if this is already something you know, but the dev tools in your browser is how you'll want to troubleshoot these sorts of issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to make sure your dependency injection is wired up properly. For example:

```js
angular
    .module("MyApp")
    .controller("MyController", ["$scope", "$timeout", MyController]);

function MyController($scope, $timeout) {
    // controller code
}
```

See [John Papa's AngularJS style guide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md#controllers) for some best practices relating to controllers.